# Downloading large file producing Network error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, base64

In the application I'm working on the users are able to upload attachments and then download them. Much like Jira. It seems though that when attempting to download large files Chrome is producing a network error and the file is not able to download. **I cannot put file size restrictions on the upload** as much as I want to. The requirements state that there should be no file size limit.

The button's content is too large to put here so I included it in a js fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/j0f9zxf2/

The html is just a simple a tag

```
 <a target="_blank" download="" class="btn btn-primary downloadAttachment" href="long string">Download</a>
```

Is there a way to fix this so they are able to download the files that are uploaded?

And just for reference. This was the file that was uploaded.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE7VzlLtp-4

Comment: If I'm understanding your issue correctly, and I may not be, as far as I'm aware Chrome has a limit on what can be formatted and downloaded from it client side. I ran into a similar issue with exporting excel documents. I believe your best bet would be to send the information server side, have it compiled into the format you want it, and have a link to the compiled document sent back to the client side for download.

Comment: @zfrisch, this data is coming from the server side unfortunately. We're not allowed to store the files, just put them in the database as a string. When your saying linking to the document that's what you mean correct?

Comment: Unfortunately that is what I mean, yes.

Comment: :( This shall be fun trying to explain to QA/management

Comment: Yep, I was right there with you. I'll upvote the question because I would be interested in an alternative answer as well.